# Redirct Error 404 to another domain on IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

i have 2 servers with 2 sub domains all of them is iis servers
1- server1.test.com (main) IIS
2- server2.test.com (backup)

i want to if the file not found on server1 change the domain to server2 and keep the whole URL

Example:
    https://server1.test.com/dir1/dir2/file.pdf  (when the file not found 404)
    redirect it to
    https://server2.test.com/dir1/dir2/file.pdf

i hope it's clear

Thanks for your help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/ Set up a dynamic page as custom error handler, and it can dispatch such requests to anywhere you like. URL Rewrite module cannot help IMHO.

Comment: In my opinion, if you want to create a backup server for the site, I suggest you could try to use IIS load balance directly. It will just use one domain. If the  load balance find the server1 return 404 error, it will not send the response to the client side directly. It will send the request to the server2 to get the right response.More details about how to set the load balance in the IIS, I suggest you could refer to this article.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/configuring-step-3-configure-iis-web-farm-load-balancing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by

i built a custom error page for error 404 in IIS by PHP to redirect from server1 to server 2
the code if it is

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "server1.com") // current domain
      header('Location: https://server2.com' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], TRUE, 301);
?>
```

then i built PHP engine in IIS from this artical
https://techexpert.tips/windows/installing-php-on-windows-server-iis/

now when server 1 send 404 error iis go to open the PHP 404 page from custom error pages and this page will re write the domain to server 2. this solution working perfectly with me